# Array is Balanced Array or Not

Tags: java, array

A `balanced array` is defined to be an array where for every value `n` in the array, `-n` also is in the array.

- `{-2, 3, 2, -3}` is a balanced array.
- So is `{-2, 2, 2, 2}`. But `{-5, 2, -2}` is not because `5` is not in the array.

I wrote the following class `BalancedArray` which satisfied above condition.

```
public class BalancedArray {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("The result is: " + isBalanced(new int[]{-2, 3, 2, -3}));
}
public static boolean isBalanced(int[] a){
    boolean status = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] > 0) {
            for(int j = i+1; j < a.length; j++) {
                if(a[i] == Math.abs(a[j])) {
                    status  =  true;

                }
            }

        } else if(a[i] < 0) {
            for(int k = i+1; k < a.length; k++) {
                if(Math.abs(a[i]) == a[k]) {
                    status = true;

                }
            }


        }
        System.out.println(status);
      if(status) {
          status= true;
      } else {
          status  = false;
          break;
      }
    }

    return status;
}
}
```

Is this proper way to check `Balanced array` or I am missing some conditions to check in array??

Comment: This isn't doing what you assume. Passing an array `{ 2 , 2 }` will result in `true`

Comment: ohh, i am missing those small conditions here @Heslacher

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: ohh! i have forget the rules and regulation of Code Review. @Heslacher

Comment: no problem  ;-) thats why I placed the comment as well

Comment: What about value `0` – is it self-balancing or does it need another `0` to satisfy `0==-0`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### From comment to answer

This isn't doing what you assume. Passing an array `{ 2 , 2 }` will result in `true`. This is because in the inner loops you don't check if the values are "oposite" meaning having a `value > 0` in the outer loop you don't check if `value < 0` in the inner loop.

The `if` condition

> ```
>   if(status) {
>       status= true;
>   } else {
>       status  = false;
>       break;
>   }
> ```

doesn't buy you anything but adds noise to the code. Simply write

```
if (!status) {
    break;
}
```

because there is no need to set `status` to `true` if thats the value anyway.

Comment: I add some validation when checking equals @Heslacher .

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way could be using a map, the average lookup time should be O(1) so this algorithm would be O(n) on average.

```
public static boolean isBalanced(int[] a) 
{     
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();  
    for(int number : a)
    {   
        int key = Math.abs(number);
        Integer value = map.get(key);

        if(value == null)
            map.put(key, number);
        else if (value != number)
            map.put(key, 0);
    }   
    for (int v : map.values())
    {
        if(v != 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

A more readable version in java 8 ( Autoboxing and unboxing may hurt the performance a lot thought.)

```
 public static boolean isBalanced(int[] a) 
 {


       Map<Integer, Integer> map = Arrays.stream(a)
                                         .boxed()
                                         .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                 Math::abs,
                                                 Function.identity(),
                                                 (x, y) -> x.equals(y)? x: 0 )
                                         );
        return map.values()
                  .stream()
                  .allMatch(p -> p == 0);
 }
```

Comment: O(nln(n)) is too expensive :p

Comment: Yep but is better than op's though. And also I gave a O(n) (on average) solution ;).

Comment: Oh sorry I just noticed that I copied your solution :(. It was brilliant anyway. Good job. You should give it a nice header like The O(n) solution or something :p

Comment: 'Note that for it to be balanced the number of elements must be even' — that's not true. The problem requires that 'for every value `n` in the array, `-n` also is in the array', but it *does not* require for every duplicated `n` to contain a *separate* `-n`; array `{1, -1, -1}` perfectly satisfies the condition: for `1` it contains `-1`, for `-1` it contains `1`.

Comment: Oops yes you are right I misread the definition. I just edited the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- Your `boolean status` is outside the loop and will remain true once set to true for any value that is balanced in the array so `{2, 3, -2}` also returns true from `isBalanced` since it is already set to true when iterating over the rest of the array for 2
- Also you don't need separate if conditions and loops for `a[i] > 0` and `a[i] < 0`. You can use a single inner loop and check `a[i] + a[k] == 0`
- You can also get rid of the if else that checks the status at the end by having loop condition as `i < a.length && status`

Comment: a[i] + a[k] == 0 could give a undesired result due to overflow, for example Integer.MIN_VALUE + Integer.MIN_VALUE is equal to 0

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm may have a square time complexity in the worst case. To make the job faster just sort the array with respect to absolute values; then perform a linear scan for groups of items with equal absolute value and test each group during the scan for the presence of 'minus the first item of a group'.

For example the array `{-2, 3, 2, -3}` might become `{-2, 2, 3, -3}`; the scan would then detect a group starting with `-2`, then find `2` equal `-(-2)` in this group; and similary item `-3` which is 'minus the first item' for the group starting with `3`.

On the other hand `{-5, 2, -2}` will become `{2, -2, -5}` or `{-2, 2, -5}` and the second group will fail the test, as it starts with `-5` but it doesn't contain `5`.

Here's a possible implementation of the scanning loop to detect groups and verify them:

```
    // ... once the array is sorted with respect to absolute values

    int groupLeader = a[0];
    int groupAbs = Math.abs(groupLeader);
    boolean groupDone = false;

    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (Math.abs(a[i]) == groupAbs) { // same group?
            if (a[i] == -groupLeader) {
                groupDone = true;
            }
        } else {                           // a new group
            if (!groupDone)    // test the previous group
                break;         // failed - return the answer

            groupLeader = a[i];    // the new group starts here
            groupAbs = Math.abs(groupLeader);
            groupDone = false;
        }
    }
    // on normal exit of the loop, groupDone contains a status
    // of the last group (and all former groups are OK)

    return groupDone;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be checking the sum of two values equals to `zero` may be the better solution for the `Balanced array`.

```
public class BalancedArray {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("The result is: " + isBalanced(new int[]{-2, 3, 2, -3}));
}

public static boolean isBalanced(int[] a) {
    boolean status = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if(a[i] + a[j] == 0) {
                status = true;
                break;
            } else {
                status = false;
            }

        }
        if(!status) {
            status =  false;
            break;
        }

    }

    return status;
}
}
```

If sum `equals zero`, `break` the loop and continue to next increment. Than, check for every status. If status is `false`, exit the loop and show `false`.